# How to include official bug fixed code for older devices

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using `AsyncTask` with my App. Everything works perfectly on new devices (4.4.x), however on older devices (say 2.3.x), an Android AysncTask bug that has been fixed appears.

If I simply copy the latest version of `AsyncTask.class` (with a name change), everything works perfectly, but is this the best thing to do?

Is there another way that I'm simply missing to get the latest version of `AsyncTask.class` into my project?

(This may not be the place for this but) if I do include the newer code version, is this now a Copyright nightmare - even though `AsyncTask.class` is already included in Android and I've only changed the name of the class?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past and solved it implementing an AsyncTask like custom class using Thread (to run **doInBackground(...)** ) and a Handler or Activity (to run code in the UI thread: **onPreExecute**, **onPostExecute**, **onProgressUpdate**). I only used this approach if:

```
Build.Version.SDK_INT < 11
```

It may not be the cleaner solution, but in production, you must act fast and be pragmatic. It worked good for me, so it did the trick.

Hope it helps.